# sql query to filter out (remove) values from column where the column values contain asterisks

Tags: sql

The following sql is returning an error.
I am trying to get the name and id from table1

```
select name,id from table1 where id!='*'
```

Answer (score 1):

if the '*' can be at any place then use this:

```
select * from table where id not like '%*%'
```